# Is there a way to quick compare items on the ground with what you have equiped?

Tags: diablo-iii

With the items that drop from monsters in Diablo 3 being pretty regular, is there an easy way to compare the item on the ground with the gear you have equipped without picking it up first and manually comparing it from your inventory?

Comment: Hmm, I was just about to say pick it up an compare it in your inventory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As long as the item does not need to be identified, you can hold Ctrl and hover over the item to show its stats. If your inventory is open as well, it will compare the ground item's stats with what you have currently equipped.

If you hold Alt and hover over with your inventory open, it will compare it to your off-hand if it is a weapon that can be dual-wield.