# Is there anyway to compare an item on the ground with an equipped item?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to quick compare items on the ground with what you have equiped?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66179/is-there-a-way-to-quick-compare-items-on-the-ground-with-what-you-have-equiped)

When an item is in my inventory I can compare it statistics against an equipped item.  Is there a way to do this with an item that is lying on the ground?

So I don't have to drop anything just to examine items with the nice comparison interface.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66179/is-there-a-way-to-quick-compare-items-on-the-ground-with-what-you-have-equiped