# How do you compare items in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

How do you compare items in your inventory to what you have equipped?

Answer (score 10):

**You will have to compare the items manually.** This feature does not exist in any automated form in Diablo II.

To find the ranges of stats on items, you will need to use a source outside of the game such as [The Arreat Summit](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/).

In **Diablo III** however, [it is possible](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66179/is-there-a-way-to-quick-compare-items-on-the-ground-with-what-you-have-equiped) to compare items in an automated fashion.

---

If you are using the popular third party Slash Diablo servers and modified client, they offer and allow [their own Maphack](https://www.reddit.com/r/slashdiablo/wiki/launcher) which shows stat ranges.

[image: An item with stat ranges shown in Slash Diablo]

Comment: Is there a way to see the 2 items side by side?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You'll have to mouseover one item, and then the other. And so on. Keep in mind that Diablo II was released in 2000, long before such convenience features were common.

Comment: @Nicole Do bear in mind that you can still screenshot the game with the tooltip for one of the items showing - paste it into Paint or whichever program you prefer. If you have two screens, slap it on the other one and you can at least see both tooltips at the same time. Otherwise you might have to screenshot the second tooltip as well and combine it with the first screenshot. It's inconvenient, but if you really feel you need to do it, that's one way of going about it. Also, if your screenshots come out completely black, put the game into windowed mode and try again.

Answer (score 8):

One way to quickly see how item A and item B affect your basic total stats is to equip them back and forth while the character stats screen is open. You'll see how your total damage, dexterity, strength, vitality, stamina and resistances change depending on which item is equipped.

Comment: That's how you did it back then! Good call.

Comment: This would work so much better if the character screen didn't frequently lie to you. Unfortunately, it does; there are all kinds of things it doesn't take into account, or just straight calculates incorrectly. Your name, level, and experience count are literally the only things on the screen that you can always rely on.

Comment: True dat, but at least it shows the approximate values. In any case, trial and error is how you usually find out if a new item works for you or not better than any stats can predict.

Comment: @KRyan This is also the case in Diablo III unfortunately

Comment: @user1306322 For some cases, it’s not even a useful approximation; granted, those are the weird cases like Dragon Tail, Dragon Talon, Smite, and Whirlwind, but still. For those skills, the numbers have almost nothing to do with the damage you actually deal.

Comment: To anyone interested, there are all sorts of online stats calculators that will show you the actual values for any items that may display incorrect stats in-game.